# Stuck in a while loop within a function (python)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to find the gender of a user. This is my code for that function:

```
def getGender():
"""figure out the gender of the person."""
gender = input("Are you male or female? (m/f)").lower()
while gender != "m" or "f":
    gender = input("Are you male or female? (m/f)").lower()

return gender
```

When I run it I keep getting stuck in the loop, even when I input a valid response.
This is the main code:

```
def main():
    welcome()
    getGender()
    if gender == "m":
        maleCalc()
        maleFinding()
    else:
        femaleCalc()
        femFinding()
    disclaimer()

#run the program
main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

I've been trying to figure out if the problem is with my function's while loop or if it's an overall logic issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If any of answers below solved your problem, please tick this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is in the section:

```
gender != "m" or "f"
```

Both "m" and "f" are treated as true in Python, and so, as != binds more tightly than or, this is the same as

```
(gender != "m") or "f"
```

which is always true.

Try instead:

```
while gender != "m" or gender != "f":
```

or

```
while gender not in ("m", "f"):
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with checking for character. You are currently checking two statements `gender != 'm'` and `"f"` and obviously the second one is always true because it's not empty. Try maybe instead something like this:

```
while (gender != "m") and (gender != "f"):
```

or equally:

```
while gender not in ["m", "f"]:
```

Thus, all in all, I would suggest modifying whole function to:

```
def getGender():
    """figure out the gender of the person."""
    gender = ""
    while gender not in ["m", "f"]:
        gender = input("Are you male or female? (m/f)").lower()

    return gender
```